# Adobe Air for iOS8: Geolocation not working

Tags: ios, flash, air, geolocation, actionscript-3

It is always muted and can't get any location permission to use GPS. Is there anyway to solve out it. Any good GPS ane recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New key-value pairs are required to access geolocation on IOS8

These are defined under "Geolocation Support" in the Adobe AIR IOS Settings documentation that can be found at

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f7e64a7f12cd2dd1867-8000.html#WS2EEDB396-2CB9-49f3-8631-81E8EE711FCE

Comment: Please explain what the link contains, since link answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Since writing this I have found a solution, 

I have changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using local shared Object, May be it will help you

https://riteshnewal.wordpress.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=130&action=edit&postpost=v2